# Removing duplicate rows?

Tags: python

Does anyone know how I might go about removing duplicate rows in the following data, where the duplicate rows are those with the same name? The catch is that I want to keep the phone numbers, emails, etc that are different in a duplicate entry.

This data is a tab-delimited text file.

Thx!

```
name    phone   email   website
Diane Grant Albrecht M.S.           
Lannister G. Cersei M.A.T., CEP 111-222-3333    cersei@got.com  www.got.com
Argle D. Bargle Ed.M.           
Sam D. Man Ed.M.    000-000-1111    dman123@gmail.com   www.daManWithThePlan.com
Sam D. Man Ed.M.            
Sam D. Man Ed.M.    111-222-333     dman123@gmail.com   www.daManWithThePlan.com
D G Bamf M.S.           
Amy Tramy Lamy Ph.D.
```

Ideal output:

```
name    phone   email   website
Diane Grant Albrecht M.S.           
Lannister G. Cersei M.A.T., CEP 111-222-3333    cersei@got.com  www.got.com
Argle D. Bargle Ed.M.           
Sam D. Man Ed.M.    000-000-1111, 111-222-333   dman123@gmail.com   www.daManWithThePlan.com
D G Bamf M.S.           
Amy Tramy Lamy Ph.D.
```

---

FOLLOW-UP:

Thoughts on this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv
import re

input = open('ieca_first_col_fake_text.txt', 'rU')

for row in input:
    row.split('\t')
    print row

# default to empty set for phone, email, website, area, degrees
extracted_data = defaultdict(lambda: [set(), set(), set()])

data_set = {}

for entry in input:

    for index, value in enumerate(entry):
        if index == 0:
            data_set = extracted_data[name]
        elif value:
            data_set[index - 1].add(value)

print data_set
```

data_set is empty ('{}')

Comment: what sort of "rows" are these? results from an sql query? a text file? xml? a dictionary?

Comment: what form is this data in?  You tagged this python but it is not clear whether this data is currently in a python dict or array or a text file or sql.

Comment: You are using `input` twice, without seeking to reposition the cursor.  The `for entry in input:` loop will do nothing, because you are already at the end of the file from the `for row in input:` loop.  Either seek or reopen the file for the second loop.  Also, look at the `with` statement for reading files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you parse the data, use a dictionary where the names are the keys and each value is a list for each additional value, each of which is in turn a set.  This will work fine as long as you don't need to maintain any associations between the data by row.

```
from collections import defaultdict
extracted_data = defaultdict(lambda: [set(), set(), set()])
# Splitting of data depends upon your input format
for entry in input:
    # Assume split() returns a 4-length iterable containing name,
    # phone, email, and url where the value is falsy if not present
    for index, value in enumerate(split(entry)):
        if index == 0:
            data_set = extracted_data[name]
        elif value:
            data_set[index - 1].add(value)
```

Comment: Would you be able to give an example entry?

Comment: @goldisfine http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples

Comment: Not sure what 'lambda' does. Googling said it generates an 'anonymous function', but doesn't seem to doing that here... instead you're setting up three more sets to store the phone, email, and website, yes?  I don't know that 'split' is the right thing because these are already split as it's a tab-delim file.

Comment: `defaultdict` takes a callable that returns a value that becomes the default value of every entry in the dictionary the first time that value is indexed in to.  The `lambda` here returns a list of 3 empty sets, so each dictionary entry defaults to a list of 3 empty sets.

Comment: Could you take a look at my follow-up?

Comment: In response to your question edit, you want `extracted_data`, not `data_set`.  And if you try to just print it, it won't be in a very readable format.  You'll have to write a printer that iterates over the extracted data and prints it in the format you  want.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`collections.defaultdict()` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to track what you already have seen:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data_so_far = defaultdict(list)

for line in inputlines:
    name = # magic to get a name

    data = data_so_far[name].add(line)
```

Now `data_so_far` contains all the data you've seen, keyed on name, each value a list of matching lines. Instead of adding a line, you can store parsed information in the list.

This *groups* your data into a structure per name.